# EC2 after restart can not access via ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I was connecting my ec2 instance via ssh well,after adding new EBS volume restarted the machine by 'sudo shutdown -r now'

And after that I tried to access by using follwing command:

```
ssh -v  -i primary_key.pem ubuntu@ec2-23-22-245-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

which is retuning like below:

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/caveman/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-23-22-245-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com [23.22.245.160] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file primary_key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file primary_key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-23-22-245-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/caveman/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: primary_key.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What is wrong?Any point that I am missing?

Comment: Have you.checked that you can log in via the AWS console? From there you can also make sure that nothing strange happened to change the hostname or key.

Comment: Yes,I have checked it,also export a new public key but its not working!

Comment: I would like one more point to @azizunsal, delete your known_hosts file from .ssh folder and then try to ssh to your instances.

Answer (score 16):

This is normal Amazon EC2  behaviour. After restarting the instance, associated public Ip (yours was `ec2-23-22-245-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com`) will be changed.

There are 2 way to connect your instance via ssh

1. Log into your Amazon AWS Console and check running instance then copy Public DNS and try to connect with ssh. (ssk key is the same)
2. If you don't want your instance's public ip to change on every restart/termination use Elastic IP. Elastic Ips associated with account (not the instance) so you can assign Elastic Ip on any instance you want.

You can connect with ssh `ssh -v  -i primary_key.pem ubuntu@<ElasticIp>`

Comment: Why do you think so? It is establishing the connection "debug1: Connection established."

Comment: This is not normal behavior, nor is "ec2-23-22-245-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com" an ip. Neither this address, nor the instance ip will change on a reboot, whether it's one issued from within the instance or done via the web UI or an ec2 CLI command. Ips and adresses may only change on a stop/start cycle.

Comment: Inaccurate terminology aside, this was SO useful. I had recreated my EC2 instance three times trying to figure out why I could only ssh in at first launch but not after a restart (although I just got a timeout with nothing helpful even from verbose). It never occurred to me that the host was changing each time. -_-

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. Here is what I did..!

```
ssh -i < .pem file> -vvv <server IP>
```

The above command will show debug logs and after ECDSA key is accepted you are in.